# saml2aws Temporary AWS credentials from Identity Provider utilizing browser based MFA in Python

Tags: python, aws-cli, playwright

**Background:**

In my quest for automation inside of a restrictive environment, I have hit a roadblock that I am not sure how to get around.

My organization uses [saml2aws](https://github.com/Versent/saml2aws) to generate temporary credentials from our identity provider.
The saml2aws setup uses "Browser" as the Provider option and points to our credentialing site where we enter username/password and then a one-time code from email.

From there, the temporary credentials are stored, and I can then interact with CLI.

My desire though is to work within these constraints to create an entirely automated process. Which I am guessing is likely going to be very "hacky" and not a best practice.

saml2aws uses [Playwright Go](https://github.com/playwright-community/playwright-go) to open Browser based IdP's.

Python is my language of choice.

**The Question(s):**

I want to attempt using saml2aws in python by utilizing "subprocess", but:

1. Is there an existing python package that can do the same thing as saml2aws instead?
2. Can Python interact with the Playwright Go browser window that saml2aws opens?

**Current code:**

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE
from shlex import split

#must run "saml2aws configure" from cmd prior to running "saml2aws login" from subprocess
#provider must be set to "Browser"

completed_process = run(split('saml2aws login --skip-prompt'), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
completed_process.stdout
```

**The Problem:**

The playwright browser window opens, but I can't take control of it to pass login/mfa token.

***Is it possible to programmatically interact with a playwright browser from python if it is opened from a command line process?***